# How to fix 'Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.'

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am making a React-redux component to embed in Laravel blade file. Where in the react side,

I am using redux with the thunk, When I try to get data without thunk from the Laravel route, it getting properly.

But When I use an axios request in the action creator to get data asynchronously. It gives the:

> 'Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.'

This is the entry component of the react side.

**Entry.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

import reducer from '../store/reducers/reducer';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

import thunk from "redux-thunk";


const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk)
+window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);
// console.log(getState());

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('like_post'));
```

This is the **App.js** main component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import axios from 'axios';
import {getCurrentPostLikes} from '../store/actions/actions';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        var domain = window.location.hostname;
        var url = window.location.pathname;
        var urlsplit = url.split("/");
        var post_slug = urlsplit[urlsplit.length - 1];

        this.state={
            post_slug: post_slug,
            post_likes:''
        }
    }

    kFormatter(num) {
        return num > 999 ? (num / 1000).toFixed(1) + 'k' : num
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getCurrentPostLikes();
        // axios.get(`/api/get_post_likes/${this.state.post_slug}`)
        // .then(response => {
        //     console.log(response.data.likes);
        //     this.setState({
        //         post_likes: response.data.likes
        //     })
        // })
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <a href="javascript:"><img src="/images/love.svg" alt="post like" width="50px" height="50px"/></a>
        <p>{this.kFormatter(this.state.post_likes)}</p>
        <p><span>{this.props.likes}</span></p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default connect(null, {getCurrentPostLikes})(App);
// export default connect( mapStateToProps, mapDispachToProps )(App);
```

This is the **actions.js** file */store/actions/actions.js*

```
// types.js is also defined properly as
// export const GET_POST_LIKES = 'GET_POST_LIKES';

import axios from 'axios';
import {GET_POST_LIKES} from './types';

// Get current post likes
export const getCurrentPostLikes = () => dispatch => {
  return dispatch => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      axios.get(`/api/get_post_likes/2`)
          .then(res => {
              // console.log(response.data.likes);
              // console.log(getState());
            setTimeout(() => {
                dispatch({
                    type: GET_POST_LIKES,
                    payload: res.data.likes
                })
            }, 4000);
          })
          .catch(err => {
              dispatch({
                  type: GET_POST_LIKES,
                  payload: {}
              })
          })
    }, 3000);
  }
}
```

Tried this action creator also, but still same error

```
export const getCurrentPostLikes = () => {
  return dispatch => {
      axios.get(`/api/get_post_likes/2`)
          .then(res => {
                dispatch({
                    type: GET_POST_LIKES,
                    payload: res.data.likes
                })
          })
          .catch(err => {
              dispatch({
                  type: GET_POST_LIKES,
                  payload: {}
              })
          })
  }
}
```

This is the **reducers.js** file under */store/reducers/reducer.js*

```
import { GET_POST_LIKES } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    likes: null
};

const reducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
    const newState = {...state};

    switch(action.type){
        case 'GET_POST_LIKES':
            return {
                ...state,
                post: action.payload
            }

        case 'LIKE_UP':
            newState.likes += action.value
            break;
    }
    return newState;
};

export default reducer;
```

Now, This should return a field value of posts table, with `post id = 2`.

Comment: The main question is why the `setTimeouts` in the action creator?? You're not returning a plain object you're returning a function...

Comment: Also tried without setTimeout, please check the updated action creator in the code, but still same error

Comment: @SakoBu, I was about to ask the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is at Entry.js, this line:

`const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk)
+window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()`

**You are setting the thunk middleware as the second parameter. The second parameter is for the initial state.** 
The thunk middleware should be part of the composed enhancers in the third parameter of the createStore function.

The parameters should be applied as such:

```
createStore(
  connectRouter(history)(rootReducer),
  initialState,
  composedEnhancers
)
```

Full example:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import { connectRouter, routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import createHistory from 'history/createHashHistory'
import rootReducer from './core/reducers'

export const history = createHistory()

const initialState = {}
const enhancers = []
const middleware = [thunk, routerMiddleware(history)]

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  const devToolsExtension = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__

  if (typeof devToolsExtension === 'function') {
    enhancers.push(devToolsExtension())
  }
}

const composedEnhancers = compose(
  applyMiddleware(...middleware),
  ...enhancers
)


export default createStore(
  connectRouter(history)(rootReducer),
  initialState,
  composedEnhancers
)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the 'signature' of an action creator curried function using redux-thunk:

```
export const getCurrentPostLikes = () => async dispatch => {
  const response = await axios.get(`/api/get_post_likes/2`);
  dispatch({ type: GET_POST_LIKES, payload: response.data.likes });
};
```

Comment: Exactly, well put.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you want your action creator to look:

```
export const getCurrentPosts = () => {
  return async function(dispatch, getState) {
    const response = await axios.get("/api/get_post_likes");
    dispatch({ type: "GET_POST_LIKES", payload: response });
  };
};
```

Leave the Promises out of it and go with ES7 `async/await` syntax and also leave out the `setTimeout`, unless you can provide a really good justification for wanting to time out an asynchronous request that is already taking a non-zero amount of time to complete, maybe I don't understand, but you do want that data don't you? It's necessary for your reducers to do their jobs and eventually update state in your application.

What I have above is not perfect in that it's boilerplate, like you don't really need `getState` in there, yes it's part of middleware, but if you are not going to use something, no need to define it. Anyway I am trying to get you to a point where your action creator works again and you are sparing your eyes and your mind.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your action has an extra `dispatch =>`

```
export const getCurrentPostLikes = () => dispatch => {

    setTimeout(() => {
      axios.get(`/api/get_post_likes/2`)
          .then(res => {
              // console.log(response.data.likes);
              // console.log(getState());
            setTimeout(() => {
                dispatch({
                    type: GET_POST_LIKES,
                    payload: res.data.likes
                })
            }, 4000);
          })
          .catch(err => {
              dispatch({
                  type: GET_POST_LIKES,
                  payload: {}
              })
          })
    }, 3000);

}
```

Comment: I have tried with this way also, without dispatch => , but doesn't working

Comment: check this: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/utils/isPlainObject.js redux use this function to determine your action is plain object.